# Can I install intellij idea on the samsung note 2?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have a smart dock for my note2 which has hdmi out and usb ports. I'd like to attach a mouse and keyboard and TV and hack on some Java projects from github. Seems like I could use this installer somehow? http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#linux

Comment: No. All the build tools included with this are x86-based code, and your Note has an ARM processor, as nearly all Android devices do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, IntelliJ IDEA is a Java Swing application designed for the standard JVMs, Android Dalvik VM will not be able to run it because it doesn't support Swing and the byte code is different.

Comment: Arch Linux Arm purports to have a version of Intellij Idea Community Edition that works. Anyone have any luck getting this to work?